# Multiple ways to invoke context manager in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-2.x, contextmanager

---

## Background

I have a class in python that takes in a list of mutexes. It then sorts that list, and uses `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` to lock/unlock all of the mutexes in a specific order to prevent deadlocks.

The class currently saves us a lot of hassle with potential deadlocks, as we can just invoke it in an [RAII style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), i.e.:

```
self.lock = SuperLock(list_of_locks)
# Lock all mutexes.
with self.lock:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.
```

---

## Problem

We'd like to expose ways for this class to provide an RAII-style API so we can lock only half of the mutexes at once, when called in a certain way, i.e.:

```
self.lock = SuperLock(list_of_locks)
# Lock all mutexes.
with self.lock:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.

# Lock the first half of the mutexes in SuperLock.list_of_locks
with self.lock.first_half_only:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.

# Lock the second half of the mutexes in SuperLock.list_of_locks
with self.lock.second_half_only:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.
```

---

## Question

Is there a way to provide this type of functionality so I could invoke `with self.lock.first_half_only` or `with self.lock_first_half_only`**`()`** to provide a simple API to users? We'd like to keep all this functionality in a single class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get this interface.  The object that will be entered/exited in context of a with statement is the resolved attribute.  So you can go ahead and define context managers as attributes of your context manager:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack  # pip install contextlib2
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def lock(name):
    print("entering lock {}".format(name))
    yield
    print("exiting lock {}".format(name))

@contextmanager
def many(contexts):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        for cm in contexts:
            stack.enter_context(cm)
        yield

class SuperLock(object):

    def __init__(self, list_of_locks):
        self.list_of_locks = list_of_locks

    def __enter__(self):
        # implement for entering the `with self.lock:` use case
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exce_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass

    @property
    def first_half_only(self):
        return many(self.list_of_locks[:4])

    @property
    def second_half_only(self):
        # yo dawg, we herd you like with-statements
        return many(self.list_of_locks[4:])
```

When you create and return a new context manager, you may use state from the instance (i.e. `self`).

Example usage:

```
>>> list_of_locks = [lock(i) for i in range(8)] 
>>> super_lock = SuperLock(list_of_locks) 
>>> with super_lock.first_half_only: 
...     print('indented') 
...   
entering lock 0
entering lock 1
entering lock 2
entering lock 3
indented
exiting lock 3
exiting lock 2
exiting lock 1
exiting lock 0
```

---

*Edit*: class based equivalent of the `lock` generator context manager shown above

```
class lock(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print("entering lock {}".format(self.name))
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exce_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("exiting lock {}".format(self.name))
        # If you want to handle the exception (if any), you may use the
        # return value of this method to suppress re-raising error on exit
```

Comment: May I please request a bit more info on this answer, and maybe a short example of instantiating/using it? Where would the `lock` and `yield` calls go? Also, would it require me to call `inst.first_half_only` or `inst.first_half_only()`? Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, may I please have an example for "creating and returning a new context manager"?

Comment: I added more context about that, pardon the pun.  The interface of the current code as written would be `with inst.first_half_only`, since that was specified in the question originally.  If an interface like `with inst.first_half_only()` is preferred, for example to pass additional arguments, then you may just remove the `@property` decorators.

Comment: Is there any particular (obvious) reason why the `__enter__()` and `__exit()__` methods always work, but calling `return many()` only works the first time around?

Comment: If I attempt to use the context twice, the example fails with `RuntimeError: generator didn't yield.`.

Comment: It seems [that `contextmanager`-supplied objects are not re-usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554981/how-to-reuse-a-custom-contextlib-contextmanager).

Comment: There is a bit in the docs about [reentrant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#reentrant-context-managers) and [reusable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#reusable-context-managers) context managers if you need that.

Comment: The docs have examples of such context managers, but don't show how to create them.

Comment: Is there a way to retain the existing API (i.e. so I can call `with super_lock.first_half_only`, or `with super_lock`), and not have to make use of `contextlib`? I don't see any decorator that allows me to create a re-entrant `contextmanager` instance.

Comment: Yes.  Using `contextlib` is not the only way to define context managers and using `@contextmanager` is probably only helpful for fairly simple use-cases.  Instead, you can make your own class-based context managers by implementing the correct API - i.e. defining `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

Comment: Could you please provide an example snippet for how I would use class-based context managers so I can retain the `with super_lock.first_half_only` property (i.e. so I don't have to re-write code to call `with super_lock.first_half_only()`), etc.)? Thank you.

Comment: I edited to show how to re-implement `lock` from first principles, instead of using the generator context manager.

Comment: Thank you. The last piece I need to figure out is what changes need to be made to `SuperLock.first_half_only` so I can retain the current API (i.e. how to make it work like a context manager without the use of `many` or the `contextlib` decorators).

Comment: On that note, is it possible to preserve the existing API with this first-principles-based approach? Or is there a simple way to change your original example so the context manager is re-entrant? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. And there are no changes needed to `SuperLock` actually, since it's already class-based.  You may re-implement `many` in a similar way as I showed with `lock` (will leave as an exercise).

Comment: Got it all figured out now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class A:

    @contextmanager
    def i_am_lock(self):
        print("entering")
        yield
        print("leaving")

a = A()

with a.i_am_lock():
    print("inside")
```

Output:

```
entering
inside
leaving
```

Futher you can use `contextlib.ExitStack` to manage your locks better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `SimpleNamespace` to allow attribute access to different `SuperLock` objects, e.g.:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

self.lock = SimpleNamespace(
    all=SuperLock(list_of_locks),
    first_two_locks=SuperLock(list_of_locks[:2]),
    other_locks=SuperLock(list_of_locks[2:])
)

with self.lock.all:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.

with self.lock.first_two_locks:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.

with self.lock.other_locks:
    # Issue calls to all hardware protected by these locks.
```

**Edit:**

For python 2, you can use this class to achieve a similar behavior:

```
class SimpleNamespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Comment: This type is not available in `python-2.x`.

Comment: That's right, but this class can easily be created in three lines of code. I updated my answer. Another option would of course be to create a real class

Comment: Just wanted to throw this in as an alternative to your solution (which I like indeed). I think it really depends on whether you need different sets of locks in differents parts of the codebase or whether it's always the same ones. In the first case, I'd like my solution better while in the latter case, I'd prefer yours.