# Python, check if called within 'with' statement

Tags: python, with-statement

I am implementing my custom `open()` function (let's call it `myOpen()`). The task is, that I would like to be able to use this function also with `with` statement (`with myOpen(...) as myFile:`). As far as I know, `open()` must return file object (`TextIO` or `BinaryIO`). But `open()` in context of `with` statement is not a function, but class, that implements `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Do you have any ideas, how to combine this two things together?
Thank you!

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546824/multiple-ways-to-invoke-context-manager-in-python

Comment: This post explains how to use `__enter__` and `__exit__` in a with expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit

Comment: When you use `with x() as y`, it is effectively assigning `y = x().__enter__()`

Comment: @Peter calling `with x() as y`, where `x()` is function, is giving me `AttributeError: __enter__` (Python 3.9.5)

Comment: Ah nvm, I reread the question, the answer is no you can't combine a context manager and a function to do both things what once. What you can do however is design a class in a way where the logic is done in `__init__` and just have `def __enter__(self): return self`. That way you get the same result with or without using `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `with` statement still returns a `_io.x` class.

```py
>>> type(open('_file_'))
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> with open('_file_') as o: print(type(o))
... 
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

The `with` statement just assigns another variable for a block of code.
Example:

```py
def five():
    return 5

print(five()) # -> 5
print(type(five())) # -> int

with five() as x:
    print(x) # -> 5
    print(type(x)) # -> int

print(x) # -> 5
```

The `with` statement is equivalent to

```py
x = five()
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

or, for the `FileIO`:

```py
handle = open('_file_')
# do things with handle
```

Comment: Thank you, well, `with five() as x` gives me `AttributeError: __enter__` (python 3.9.5). Another question would be how can I handle `__exit__` in `myOpen()`? How can I close file descriprot in `myOpen()` function, when `with` statement exists?

Comment: make a class with for your special filehandle, with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out where was a problem. At the beginning I thought, that `with` statement can be called only on class, which has those magic methods (`__enter__` and `__exit__`). So:

```py
with class_that_has_those_methods as return_value_from_enter:
    pass
```

But it works different. Expression after `with` can be also function, but it has to return instance of class, which implements those magic methods. I think, that this is also the way, how python's `open` works. It is function, which returns file object (more precisely wrapper):

```py
>>> type(open)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(open('file', 'w'))
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

and that file object implements those magic methods:

```py
>>> a = open('file', 'w')
>>> dir(a)
[... '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', ...]
```

So to solve my original problem, `myOpen()` has to be function, which returns file object, that has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.